# Calling Web API vs adding reference to underlying dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, architecture, asp.net-web-api2

This is more of an Architecture question, and I want to know all the possible pros and cons of the approach.

In my org, we have an ASP.NET Application, a Web API Project, and underlying DLLs which calls App Tier which is physically on different server. In ASP.NET Application, for a particular piece, we are having a SPA.

For most of the things (I would say 99 % of the things) , we are making ajax call from our SPA to Web-API to access underlying functionality.

SPA and WebAPI are both deployed and hosted on same Web Server as different applications and WebAPI has reference to underlying DLLs so these DLLs are deployed with WebAPI.

For one of the functionality some server side processing needs to be done on ASPX page's code behind.

I am suggesting to my team to do keep calling from SPA to WebAPI using http client and maintain loose coupling that we have between Application and the dlls via WebAPI, but many (I would say everybody else in my team) is in favor of adding direct reference of DLLs to ASP.NET application, so now these DLLs will be deployed with ASP.NET Application alongside.

Is my suggestion not so good provided ease of implementation that we would be getting with adding direct reference for DLLs in ASP.NET Application? Let me know if I am not explanatory enough.

Comment: It would be easier to read your question if you simply called them "web app" and "web api" instead of a, w, d and e. It makes it confusing.

Comment: generally, having ui reference same dlls as webapi violates entire concept of having a webapi.

i hear this argument and it's typically because team finds wiring up webapi calls "overkill" . . . however, benefit of having data access hidden from consuming application is huge.

we have to manipulate data returned from webapi, either in the code-behind or in javascript . . . either way, we get data from webapi, then mutate data as needed for the consumer. i'm having trouble seeing use case where web application bypassing webapi to reference same data layer dlls makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be in favor of using a DLL directly if you could get rid of the Web API altogether. Since it does not sound like you are planning to do that, I think your suggestion to continue using the Web API from your application:

- Using the DLL from two places creates a deployment liability: every time you update it, both places must be updated
- Changing the code in DLL requires testing the change from two paths - A-D and A-W-D
- Fixing a bug in the way that you call your DLL would likely have to go to both A and W, instead of going to W alone.

Of course, the path A-W helps you exercise your Web API component, too, helping you detect bugs early.

Comment: I agree with your points in the sense that only one approach should be followed and thats what I am also in support. 99 % of the things in application is done using Web-API. Its one one or two functionality that is needing some server side processing and for this ppl in my team are going for dual approach.